# SSIS executed on another server

Tags: ssis

I have a server AAA with SQL Server and Integration Services installed. Here I have a bunch of SSIS packages stored in the file system. They use some local folders (i.e. C drive) and the local database for ETL processing. I am forced to launch the packages from Integration Services because some of them require input parameters. So I cannot run them as jobs.

Now... I have another server named BBB with Integration Services and I need to launch from here SSIS packages hosted on server AAA. So I connect to Integration Services from AAA and launch a package. It fails because it runs on BBB context and it tries to access a folder from C drive located on BBB server. So it looks for me that the SSIS package runs in the BBB server context. Can run the SSIS package in AAA server context?

Comment: "hosted on the file system" So this is 2005/2008 or the packages were developed using the Package deployment model? When you specify input parameters, how are you doing so?

Comment: There is nothing fancy about deployment... I copy the dtsx file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Packages and I see it "Stored Packages - File System"when I connect to Integration Services.    The package has a "Script Task" and there is something like Dim myValue = InputBox ("bla-blah-blah....") which shows a dialog box to the user

Comment: Ah. Generally speaking, SSIS packages should run unattended. Were it me, I'd rework your approach to have a dedicated UI for parameter value collection. Knowing my values, I'd then launch a remote process on the AAA server. You can either use dtexec /set to specify your variable values. Or you could look at creating a self deleting SQL Agent job with those input parameters and then starting the job. Or you could write the values to a SQL Server table. Rework the SSIS package to pull configuration from that table and then the final step of the process is to delete the row used for config.